# Bean of Interface type could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller

first of all I would like to say that I've read simmilar questions and implemented thier answers, but nothing seems to work. 
TL;DR I'm implementing an example from a book "Spring" and here's my problem.
A starting class:

```
package com.example.demo;
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.example.demo", "com.example.demo.dao", "com.example.demo.model", "com.example.demo.service"})
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

A Controller class:

```
package com.example.demo.api;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/spittles")
public class SpittleController {
    private SpittleRepository a;
    @Autowired
    public SpittleController(@Qualifier("abc") SpittleRepository a){
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
package com.example.demo.dao;
@Repository("abc")
public interface SpittleRepository {
    List<Spittle> findSpittles(long max, int count);
}
```

My Output:

```
Description:
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.api.SpittleController required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.dao.SpittleRepository' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="abc")
```

As I said before, the example is literally copied from the book (I simplified it for the purpose of the question). The only situation where this program does not throw an error is when I add the annotation: `@ComponentScan("com.example.demo.dao")`to the DemoApplication class (but works only if there is one file inside dao). Alternatively, when I replace the interface keyword with a class keyword, it also works.

Is there any way to make the class (DemoApplication) to find this interface?

Comment: 1.[`@SpringBootApplication`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-structuring-your-code) will do a component scan for all packages under `com.example.demo` , so it is not required to explicitly mention the base packages. 2. Create a class and implement the interface `SpittleRepository` and annotate the new class with `@Component`.Run the code and let us know the results

Comment: 2. I agree, I've tried this solution and it works, but is it impossible to autowire only interface? (the Guy in The book just did it)

Comment: Please confirm if in the tutorial the repository extends something like this `public interface SpittleRepository extends JpaRepository<Spittle, Long> {}`

Comment: I will qoute the book:"
To begin with, we will define a data access repository. To separate data
and not delve into the details of the database, we will define a repository
in the form of an interface, and we will deal with the implementation later (in Chapter 10.). At this moment
all we need is an interface to download the list of spittle" Here is code from the book:```public interface SpittleRepository {
 List<Spittle> findSpittles(long max, int count);
}```

Comment: and how is the implementation done in Chapter 10 ? Some implementation for that interface is required for it to work , isn't it ?

Comment: At chapter 5, the author runs a unit test and it fails, than (few pages later) he autowires Interface with Controller, adds jsp page and runs the whole app. After that, there is a screen of app working. To be honest, i think it is possible (after all, I can autwire it with ComponentScan), but something doesn't work right without it.

Comment: An implementation is required for the program to run . Either you implement one or use spring data jpa to build one for you automatically.

Comment: Ok, I'm grateful for Your help Sir, you saved me probably a week of digging, I'l probably just change the book.

Comment: Glad that I could help. Shall I convert this to an answer and you can mark it closed ?

Comment: Yes, please, thank You!

Comment: Also , the best resource is Springs official [reference documentation](https://spring.io/docs/reference). Good Luck

Comment: I'l try this! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [@SpringBootApplication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-structuring-your-code) will do a component scan for all packages under com.example.demo , so it is not required to explicitly mention the base packages.
2. Create a repository class and implement the interface `SpittleRepository` and anotate the new class with `@Component`. An implementation for the interface is required here.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.demo.dao;
@Repository
public interface SpittleRepository {
    List<Spittle> findSpittles(long max, int count);
}
```

---

```
package com.example.demo.api;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/spittles")
public class SpittleController {
    private SpittleRepository a;
    @Autowired
    public SpittleController(@Qualifier("spittleRepository ") SpittleRepository a){
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly it also throws the same error: "required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.dao.SpittleRepository' that could not be found."